# input map value into another map name in jsp page

Tags: java, jsp, foreach, modelandview

I want to generate tables in jsp page using data I got from Map in java. I use  which use map value for define 'item'. But, The name of map value that I want to put on 'item' needs value from another map.

To be clear, here my jsp code;

```
    <c:forEach var="wilayahProvinsi" items="${model.kodeKabupatenList}">
<div data-role="page"  id="kode${wilayahProvinsi.ID2012}">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="inline"  data-fullscreen="true">     
        <a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-icon-arrow-l ui-btn-icon-notext ui-shadow ui-corner-all" data-rel="back">Back</a>
        <h1>${wilayahProvinsi.NAMA}</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
        <table id="example1" class="display nowrap" >
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Kode Komoditas</th>
                    <th>Jenis Barang</th>
                    <th>Nilai Konsumsi</th>
                    <th>Nilai Imputasi</th>
                    <th>Nilai Konsumsi Akhir</th>
                    <th>Persentase trhdp Total</th>
                    <th>Persentase trhdp Kelompok</th>
                    <th>Persentase trhdp Subkelompok</th>
                    <th>Edit</th>
                    <th>Delete</th>
                </tr>
            <tbody>
                <!-- this is the problem -->
                <c:forEach var="pekerjaanku" items="${model.pekerjaankuList$wilayahProvinsi.ID2012}">
                <tr>
                    <td>${pekerjaanku.kode_komoditas}</td>
                    <td id="jenis_barang">${pekerjaanku.jenis_barang}</td>
                    <td style="text-align: right">${pekerjaanku.nilai_konsumsi}</td>
                    <td style="text-align: right">${pekerjaanku.nilai_imputasi}</td>
                    <td style="text-align: right">${pekerjaanku.nilai_konsumsi_akhir}</td>
                    <td style="text-align: right">${pekerjaanku.persentase_total}</td>
                    <td style="text-align: right">${pekerjaanku.persentase_kelompok}</td>
                    <td style="text-align: right">${pekerjaanku.persentase_subkelompok}</td>
                    <td><a href="kotaEdit?id=${pekerjaanku.kode_komoditas}" class="ui-btn ui-mini ui-corner-all ui-icon-edit 
                            ui-btn-icon-left">Edit</a></td>
                    <td><a href="kotaDelete?id=${pekerjaanku.kode_komoditas}" class="ui-btn ui-mini ui-corner-all ui-icon-delete 
                            ui-btn-icon-left" onclick="return confirm('Yakin ingin menghapus komoditas ${pekerjaanku.jenis_barang}?')">
                            Delete</a></td>
                </tr>
                </c:forEach>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="8"><a href="kotaTambahKomoditas" style="text-align:center">Tambah Komoditas Baru</a></td>
                <td colspan="2"><a href="provinsiDownloadCSV/diagramtimbang" target="_blank">Download CSV</a></td>              
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
</c:forEach>
```

This is my Java code;

```
    @RequestMapping("/jelajahPekerjaanKota")
public ModelAndView getPekerjaanKotaList() {
    List<KodeKabupaten> kodeKabupatenList = usersService.getSpecifiedKodeKabupatenList();
    Map<String, Object> model = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    model.put("kodeKabupatenList", kodeKabupatenList);
    for(KodeKabupaten kodeKabupaten : kodeKabupatenList){
        model.put("pekerjaankuList" + kodeKabupaten.getID2012(), pekerjaankuService.getPekerjaankuList(kodeKabupaten.getID2012()));
    }

    return new ModelAndView("/provinsi/jelajahPekerjaanKota", "model", model);
}
```

To be clear, the objects in Map model is;

- model.kodeKabupatenList which has attributes: NAMA, ID2012, PROV, and KAB
- model.pekerjaankuList3171 which has attributes: kode_komoditas, jenis_barang, ...
- model.pekerjaankuList3172 , the attributes are same with above
- model.pekerjaankuList3173 , same with above

my problem is how to get all model.pekerjaankuList** in jsp with looping? I can not run this code in jsp;

```
 <c:forEach var="pekerjaanku" items="${model.pekerjaankuList$wilayahProvinsi.ID2012}">
```

Comment: You don't name things dynamically. Change code so `kodeKabupatenList` is a `Map<Integer, KodeKabupaten>`.